Is still safe have 2 cookies with the same information and name but one has httponly enabled
I have a asp classic site, I want to set the httponly enabled to the cookies ASPSESSIONIDxxxx, I applied this in general.asp file which is called when the site is loaded:
AspSessionCookie = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE")

' Split the cookies by the semicolon delimiter
cookies = Split(AspSessionCookie, ";")


' Loop through cookies again to find the ASPSESSIONID and set it with HttpOnly
For i = 0 To UBound(cookies)
    If InStr(cookies(i), "ASPSESSIONID") > 0 Then
        ' Extract the ASPSESSIONID cookie value
        Dim cookieValue
        cookieParts = Split(cookies(i), "=")
        cookieName = Trim(cookieParts(0))
        cookieValue = Trim(cookieParts(1))
        ' Set the ASPSESSIONID cookie with HttpOnly attribute
        Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", cookieName & "=" & cookieValue & "; HttpOnly"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

the code works, but when I inspect network applications, I have now 2 cookies, the mine, of my site with URL "/mysite", with the httponly enabled, and another exact the same name and value, but with the URL "/"  and httponly disabled, my question is still valid my code to avoid site hacks or I need to keep researching for a better solution?

Non http-cookies is accesible  to client-side scripts, which defeats the purpose of setting the HttpOnly attribute. XSS attacks involve injecting malicious scripts into web pages viewed by other users. These scripts can steal cookies and other sensitive information. By marking cookies as HttpOnly, you ensure they are not accessible via JavaScript, mitigating the risk of theft via XSS.
When a cookie is set with the Secure attribute, it is only transmitted to the server when the request is made over an HTTPS connection. This means the cookie will not be sent over unencrypted HTTP connections.
so to secure the cookie and site you could use the below iis url rewrite rule which will help you to set  Secure and HttpOnly flag:
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>  
        <rule name="Use only secure cookies" preCondition="Unsecured cookie">  
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE" pattern=".*" negate="false" />  
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />  
        </rule>  
        <preConditions>  
            <preCondition name="Unsecured cookie">  
            <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="." />  
            <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />  
        </preCondition>  
        </preConditions>  
    </outboundRules>  
</rewrite>

